# What is an elegant way to convert IDictionary<string, object> to IDictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method I am not happy with, can you please show me how to do this better.

```
public Foo WithBar(IDictionary<string, object> parameters) {
    var strStrDict = new Dictionary<string, string>(parameters.Count);
    foreach(var pair in parameters)
    {
        strStrDict.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value != null ? pair.Value.ToString() : (string)null);
    }      
    // Call overload which takes IDictionary<string, string>  
    return this.WithBar(strStrDict);
}
```

This code works but I'm sure there is a nice linq'y way of doing this I am missing.

Comment: One reason you should be unhappy with your method: It's broken! `pair.Value == null ? pair.Value.ToString() : (string)null` should blow up quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I asked the question and went off to write the unit test. So just found that.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick nice answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
parameters.ToDictionary(k=>k.Key, v=>v.Value!=null?v.Value.ToString():(string)null);
```

Comment: That construct is called `as` ;)

Comment: @dykam, absolutely not. `as` performs a reference conversion, which will return null if the object is not a string. `ToString` returns a string representation of the object, which is something completely different...

Comment: Technically, `(string)null` is not required. In the expression `condition ? obj.ToString() : null;` the compiler has enough information to determine the type of the expression to be a string.

Comment: @Thomas Levesque, I assumed he had a Dict<string, object> where all keys where strings, so he just needed a cast. That still doesn't make `as`equivalent to your code indeed.

Answer (score 4):

```
parameters.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => Convert.ToString(v.Value))
```

`Convert.ToString()` returns `null` on null-values which you would expect.

**Update:**

`Convert.ToString(object)` returns `String.Empty` but `Convert.ToString(string)` returns `null`. Unfortunately, that is *not* what you need. Weird definition in my opinion :-/

Comment: Convert.ToString(null) return String.Empty http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh.aspx, and failed my unit test :)

Comment: Interesting twist. In LinqPad (about to test in VS), `Convert.ToString(null)` returns null, but `object obj = null; Convert.ToString(obj)` returns empty string.

Comment: @David Waters I see :) I apparently tested against the wrong `Convert.ToString` (see updated answer). @Anthony Pegram Yeah, it takes the most "concrete" overload it can.

Comment: yes, the documentation supports your edit. When passed `null` explicitly, overload resolution is picking the `string` version, which returns the string unchanged (hence getting null back). Since `null` works for object and string, overload resolution chooses the more specific type, which is string. Edit: Or what you just said.

Answer (score -1):

```
parameters.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value.ToString())  // out of my head
```

Comment: You will get an exception on null-values.